# Flutter directly run some Skia operations?

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, skia

I have a widget showing an image and some `dart:ui Path`s. The problem is, I need some graphics operations to this combination. For example (as a simplified requirement), I need to subtract the image by the Paths, dilate it (Skia does have a dilate image filter), and combine with the image and Paths, etc.

The problem is, I have not found any way to directly manipulate at the Skia level. I wonder how can I do this? Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, Flutter doesn't expose the Skia API, thus making it hard to do (not sure if it's even possible). This is because Flutter also supports web, which is not using Skia, Flutter only exposes their Widget composing api.

Comment: Yes, and nowadays they are adding impeller which is also not skia